# How to fix infinite yield possible in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to code a main menu for my game but I get this error:
Infinite yield possible on 'Players.Username.PlayerGui.Menu:WaitForChild("Sidebar")'
And this is my code:
    wait(5)

```
--Service
local Tween = game:GetService("TweenService")
--Variables
local Sidebar = script.Parent: WaitForChild("Sidebar")
local PlayBtn = Sidebar: WaitForChild("Play")
local CreditsBtn = Sidebar: WaitForChild("Credits")
local Title = Sidebar: WaitForChild("Title")



Tween:Create(
 Sidebar,
TweenInfo.new(0.4, Enum.EasingStyle.Quad, 
Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 0, false, 0),
{Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)}
):Play()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that :WaitForChild() couldn't find the Sidebar object, thus, erroring out.

You've gotta reconfigure Sidebar's value so that it can find the object itself via experimenting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It worked after I tried changing the letters

Answer (score 0):

to stop the infinite yield possible you need to add a timeout to the wait

Example:

```
wait_time = 5
local Sidebar = script.Parent: WaitForChild("Sidebar", wait_time)
```

you can also replace wait_time with anything (and you can just put the number in the wait for child if you want)
you don't have to set it to a low number, you can set it to 999999999999999999999 if you want it to just not yield but also keep waiting